# F90 Interpolation from non-constant-resolution 3D grid to a constant resolution grid

Tags: 3d, fortran, interpolation

I have data on a 3D cartesian grid with varying resolution. The grid is still structured, in that the x resolution is only a function of x, same for y,z. I need to interpolate this data onto a constant resolution grid of approximately the same size. Typical sizes are 256^3, 512^3.

Tri-linear interpolation won't cut it due to the noisy data, whch leaves higher order (for accuracy or smoothness, I have yet to decide which will be best). I am aware of the software
http://jacobwilliams.github.io/bspline-fortran/ but this states that it works on a regular grid. If "regular" means constant resolution, then this may not help my problem. However, I may have misinterpreted what they mean by "regular".

Is anyone aware of open source fortran software that can be used for my problem? Namely  interpolation from one large 3d grid (non-constant-resolution) to a new 3D grid (constant resolution), that is more than tri-linear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The term 'regular' grid is not used as often as 'uniform grid' (which your grid is not) and 'structured grid' (which it is). The specifications of bspline-fortran seem to indicate that the interpolation works for structured, rectilinear, stretched grids, so I suppose that this is the definition of 'regular' grid in your case. The good news is that your grid is 'regular' by that definition.

The important question for your case is whether your nonuniform grid is the result of a 'smooth transformation function'. If it is, your grid can be seen as a uniform grid in 'transformed space', and you can use the available 3D interpolations.

My advice is to try it and find some way to evaluate the accuracy.